Clicking on button or href link closes browser tab
I have a URL link linking to an HTML page (page A). Page A has a meta refresh forward - although I  tried JS on load as well - to another page (Page B). Sometimes clicking the button opens Page A which instantly forwards to the correct Page B, while many times it just closes the tab. Tried all browsers desktop and mobile doesn't matter.
One detail, if I type the address of Page A it always forwards to Page B, no issues. The is just an ordinary A href, nothing fancy.
Expected that the link always should open Page A and then instantly Page B. 50% Works, 50% closes the tab altogether. Tried different redirect options and delayed meta refresh, no luck.
